# Почему динамическая память это плохо?

Tags: динамические-массивы, динамические-структуры

На сайтах, наподобие [leetcode.com](https://leetcode.com/), есть много очень хороших задач и решая их, ты сразу можешь понять насколько эффективна твоя программа в плане памяти и скорости. Но во многих разборах задач я часто встречал советы не использовать динамическую память. Почему?

Comment: Потому что *в рамках спортивного программирования* :) Например, есть соревнования на краткость кода - а тут вы видите, насколько длиннее `std::vector<int>`, чем просто `<int>` :) Отвлекаясь - если бы я был руководителем программистской конторы, то последний, кого бы я брал на работу - вот такой программист... Проще научить кого с нуля, чем переучить "спортсмена" писать понятный, поддерживаемый код...

Comment: динамическая память не при чем, наоборот для массивов и крупных обьектов наоборот ее нужно юзать, а не класть в стэк, так эффективнее  работает. @Harry ура нашел плюс, что не стал заниматься спортивным программированием, хотя они там все алгоритмы и структуры данных наизусть знают :)

Comment: Вы думаете что в спортивном программировании сплошь и рядом объекты? Вы ошибаетесь по этому поводу. Ваши коментарии только говорят об этом. Как вы можете спорить о спорте когда вы сами не в теме? Диванные войска и только, вот что мне видеться глядя на Вас.

Comment: А вот грубить не нужно....    Человек просто задал вопрос.

Comment: И в мыслях не было грубить. Если человек не втеме то зачем оправдывать свои действия, делая снисходительный тон мол хорошо что не занимался? А что делать тем кто ради страны занимается этим? Для гордости тех кто не занимается вовсе?

Comment: Можете представить так: когда у автослесаря(спортивное программирование) инструменты разбросаны по разным гаражам, и он не может сам выполнять свою работу, то это плохо. Он должен держать все инструменты компактно, чтобы быстро пользоваться ими и должен уметь делать свою работу эффективно. Но  транспортная компания(реальная программа) не может работать в пределах одной площади, она должна иметь много чего(не будем перечислять) и должна поддерживать много связей с другими отраслями и иметь работников разного состава,  может увеличивать и уменьшать их количество по мере нужды.

Comment: @AzizUmarov если вы на счет моего комментария то я имел ввиду, что у спорт программирования один минус как раз только вижу, это то что нужно быстро писать код, ни кого не хотел обидеть

Comment: Идея спорта в целом сменить арену боевых действий между людьми на более гуманную где нет крови и боли в том масштабе в котором может нести противостояние в целом.  Быстрее выше сильнее как говориться. Заниматься этим или нет выбор каждого, но не забываем о чувствах тек кто сделал свой выбор. Я уважаю ваше решение. Критиковать могут все, а чемпионами становитс не каждый.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не занимался спортивным программированием, потому опишу с точки зрения реальных задач. Подозреваю, недоверие к динамической памяти в спортивном программировании идет из С, где было легко получить утечку памяти, а также связано с невозможностью использования сторонних библиотек.

Если говорить о  производительности, то нужно уточнить, что сейчас немногие процессоры реализуют аппаратный стек, в большинстве случаев стек - это заранее выделенный кусок динамической памяти с теми же свойствами. В этом плане отличаются матричные процессоры (видеокарты), и некоторые микроконтроллеры, но их рассматривать не будем. Таким образом, на практике вопрос сводится не столько к использованию динамической памяти, сколько к выбору между структурами фиксированного и переменного размера. Если размер задачи известен, ничего не мешает выделить массив фиксированного размера в динамической памяти, компилятор сможет применить те же оптимизации, что и при его создании на стеке (но тут речь идет именно о формальном фиксированном размере, между `vector<int> v(32)` и `new std::array<int, 32>{}` есть разница).

У самостоятельного выделения динамической памяти есть два недостатка: относительно низкая скорость выделения (и, возможно, освобождения) и возможность фрагментации (и связанные с этим проблемы локальности данных). Для массивов достаточно большого размера это не актуально - по сравнению с затратами на их обработку, затраты на выделение памяти незначительны.

Проблемы с динамической памятью начинаются при создании множества маленьких объектов. В C++ во многих случаях ничего не мешает объединять несколько малых объектов в большой класс, или массив, и реально проблема возникает при использовании динамических структур данных типа списков, деревьев и графов. И тут задача сводится к выбору подходящих структур и алгоритмов.

К проблеме обычно рекомендуется подходить так: нужно применять самые общие подходы для оптимизации, но сохранение читаемости кода должно быть в приоритете. Необходимость оптимизации должна доказываться профилированием.

Если говорить об удобстве использования, то и для структур фиксированного размера есть удобные интерфейсы. Есть `std::array`, предлагающий интерфейс С++ для массивов фиксированного размера. Для математических задач есть библиотека Eigen, предоставляющий интерфейсы для матриц фиксированного и динамического размера (и можно выбирать между column major и row major). И есть интересный вариант массивов с фиксированным максимальным размером, но меняющимся реальным (по сути, обертка над обычным массивом фиксированного размера, мешающая обращению к не инициализированному куску массива). Она может быть реализована как vector + fixed_size_allocator.

Еще есть кортежи (tuple), позволяющие объединять в подобие массива фиксированного размера структуры разного типа.

Есть small vector optimisation и small string optimisation, когда массивы/строки малого размера создаются как массив с фиксированным максимальным размером, но при достижении этого максимального размера выделяется динамическая память. Разработчики llvm, например, активно используют такие.

В общем, вопрос не имеет однозначного ответа, для каждой задачи свои решения и на практике у нас не всегда есть возможность выбрать лучшее.

Answer (score 4):

В спортивном программировании не заморачиватются и пишут прямо в задании памяти и столько времени на каждый тесть. Учитывая что, динамика это время на выделение, никто терять его не хочет учитывая что его не хватает. В спортивном программировании нет проверок типа защиты от дурака, введите ещё ... Никто не собирается проверять мощь С с Java примеру. Задача решенная на одном языке должно иметь эквивалент на другом и выбор языка абсолютно не должно иметь значения.